# api/resources?metrics=profile is not returning result in sonarqube 4.5.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am accessing sonarqube web service api to fetch sonar dashboard data. One of the metrics key is **profile** to get quality profile used for analysis.

With previous version of sonar(**3.7.2**) I am able to do it. But with sonarqube (**4.5.4**) I am not.

I can see the profile metrics key under api/metrics. But I am not getting value for it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're confusing metric *key* with metric *id*, which should be numeric.